# How to let racket-mode handle language extensions (the #lang directive)?

Tags: repl

I was wondering how to let `racket-mode` handle [racket language extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_features#Language_extensions) properly?

I tried the following file from the link above (`test.rkt`):

```
#lang datalog

ancestor(A, B) :- parent(A, B).
ancestor(A, B) :-
  parent(A, C), D = C, ancestor(D, B).
parent(john, douglas).
parent(bob, john).

ancestor(A, B)?
```

After `C-c C-z`, (which launches the REPL with `; Welcome to Racket v8.5 [cs]...`),
I was able to load the extension if I send the whole buffer (`C-c C-c`, or `racket-run-module-at-point`) to the REPL.

```
> 
ancestor(bob, john).
ancestor(john, douglas).
ancestor(bob, douglas).
test.rkt> 
; Closing REPL session because language's current-read-interaction returned EOF

Process *Racket REPL </>* connection broken by remote peer
```

But I cannot execute individual regions (and the REPL is terminated). If I just do `C-c C-r` (`racket-send-region`) on the first line (or few lines), including the `#lang` directive, I get an error:

```
; :2:0: read-syntax: `#lang` not enabled
;   possible reason: not allowed again inside a module that already starts `#lang`, or not enabled for interactive evaluation
; datalog: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
;   in module: top-level
>
```

*How to configure Emacs racket-mode in order to make `racket-send-region` work in above?*

(This is with Emacs 28, racket-mode from MELPA, under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't a configuration issue but an issue with `#lang datalog` and how it interacts (or not) with `racket-mode`. There are some more detailed discussions about it [here](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/issues/305) and [here](https://github.com/racket/datalog/issues/9) which could provide another angle.